# How to bid for a spot instance with price: 0.0164

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I looked at the charts of last week's EC2 prices for m1.large in us-east-1c, and I saw prices like: 0.0160, 0.0161, 0.0162, 0.0163 so clearly there must be a way to bid for prices like this, but when I try to create a cluster using the amazon elastic-mapreduce ruby cli, then I get this error:

```
Error: No more than 3 digits are allowed after decimal place in bid price
```

There must be a way to do this other than bidding for 0.017

Answer (score 0):

The bid price you provide is the maximum price you are willing to pay for that instance. As such, the vast majority of time you are actually paying less than that price you specify. Perhaps that's why there is no need for more than three digits; the bidding perhaps isn't lost or won by such a small margin as below the third decimal, etc.

Comment: I doubt this is the correct answer, because according to the algorithm amazon uses to determine the prices they use the highest bidding prices, so there must be someone who was able to bid for a price like 0.0161 and I am only able to bid for 0.016 or 0.017

Comment: You should check your billing info. With spot instances, I bet you have paid less than what your actual bid price indicates. At least that was the case with my jobs. I don't have access to EMR right now, but you can also bid on the EMR console and specify your bid price there. If it is ever possible, you should be able to specify more than 3 digits somewhere, I suppose. But if it's not possible at all, I suspect the reason is that bidding war like that simply doesn't make sense. You don't want your instances taken away because someone outbid you by 0.000001 dollar. Looks like a disaster to me.